# How do I find a value in a JSON block if the id is in the same array as the value?

Tags: javascript

I would like to be able to retrieve the values in the following json block by referencing the id. I have so far been using the order they appear in to reference the value i need to get (eg. items[1].values[0].value) but this isn't great because they may change order).

I am using pure js - if that possible.

```
"items": [
  {
    "id": "0",
    "position": 0,
    "value": "test"
  },
  {
    "values": [
      {
        "position": 0,
        "value": "One location"
      }
    ],
    "id": "2",
    "position": 1
  }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find` to search for the first match.

```js
let obj = {"items": [{"id": "0","position": 0,"value": "test"},{"values": [{"position": 0,"value": "One location"}],"id": "2","position": 1}]}

let id = '2';
let result = obj.items.find(o => o.id === id);

console.log(result);
```

Doc: [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

---

If you are expecting multiple matches, you can use `filter`

```js
let obj = {"items": [{"id": "0","position": 0,"value": "test"},{"values": [{"position": 0,"value": "One location"}],"id": "2","position": 1},{"id": "2","position": 0,"value": "SOme other values"}]}

let id = '2';
let result = obj.items.filter(o => o.id === id);

console.log(result);
```

Doc: [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
var array1 = [
   {
    "id": "0",
    "position": 0,
    "value": "test"
  },
  {
    "values": [
      {
        "position": 0,
        "value": "One location"
      }
    ],
    "id": "2",
    "position": 1
  }
];

var found = array1.find(function(element) {
  return element.position === 1;
});

console.log(found);

if(found.values) {
  var subfind = found.values.find(function(element) {
    return element.position === 0;
  });
  
  console.log(subfind);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - I need more practice with the .find function.

I ended up using -

```
items.find(o => o.id === '0').value
```